# Fancybox 2.0 easing and animation

Tags: jquery, fancybox, jquery-animate, easing

Is it possible to have some examples on how to use nextEasing and prevEasing parameters with fancybox 2.0? If I add the easing plugin 1.3 and then I use easing animation value like easeInCubic nothing happens. How to achieve new types of transition.

I would also like to have with this new version 2.0 the same effect of resizing/adapting frame I had with the previous version 1.3.4 when I slide from a picture to another.

```
$("a.image").fancybox({
    arrows   : true,
    loop       : false,
    openEffect : 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none',
    prevEffect : 'fade',
    nextEffect : 'fade',
    prevEasing : 'easeInCubic',
    nextEasing : 'easeInCubic',
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to use the easing option, but I didn't find the doc to have all the allowed values on fancybox website, all I could find was:

> Easing method for each transition type. You have numerous choices **if** easing plugin is included
>   String; Default value: 'swing'

If I try to use the value 'easeInCubic', I can see in the Javascript console of my browser:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'easeInCubic' jquery-latest.min.js:6
```

Not sure if it was your case too, but you need to make sure to include/activate the easing plugin, which is not part of fancy box, by adding this

```
<!-- Easing plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js" />
```

At the top of my HTML solved the Javascripts errors. Having a look at [this demo](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/effect/easing.html) shows what does each value. The difference between the default value and `easeInCubic` isn't very big.

That said, for what you want to achieve, this option doesn't seem to be the good one, you can find an example with [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PwMjP/), which seems much more appropriate.

Comment: It's been a while since I tried to resolve this. Since then I totally changed the javascript plugin I'm using. In any case your solution for the resizing transition effect seems a good one! Many thanks!